# Qt5: How to create interrupt driven gpio button based qt app

Tags: c++, qt5

My problem is......... I am trying to develop an application.In this application there are certain pages and which is displaying on the LCD on my board.and my board has a gpio button by default the value of this button is high when i press this button value of this button become low after releasing again high.i want to make my app interrupt based when i pressed hold button for 3 second display should be rotate and if i just press and release button page should change.In my app i have interface my gpio button.

```
QString btnInput = "/sys/class/gpio/gpioN/value";
```

In my apps I can read the value from value file when my app start after that if i press button nothing will happen.what should i do.
how can i generate interrupt after pressing button.

please help me i am new in qt I start qt just before 2 week.

Answer (score 0):

I can't tell for a Qt5 application actually (I don't have experience in the Qt field), but you may use a [`inotify`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/inotify.7.html) file watcher with `/sys/class/gpio/gpioN/value` in user space.

That way your program will receive notifications (interrupts) whenever the value changes.

I'm almost sure there's also some (portable) Qt intrinsic mechanism, that resembles the same.

---

Update (after a little research):

Specifically for Qt I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/931165/1413395) where the [`QFileSystemWatcher`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qfilesystemwatcher.html) is mentioned for doing that portably.

Comment: Thank you sir for reply  and i  implemented it based upon changes it is generating interrupt  but SIGNAL fileChanged() gets emited only once.but i want when ever i press the button interrupt should generate. please help me.

Comment: QFileSystemWatcher is not the specific command to use. It can not figure the system files changed. Maybe this link is useful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23823279/handle-gpio-button-event-with-c